# Vehicle not doing slow running

Tags: toyota, idle, camshaft, highlander

My highlander 2004 slow run is fine before taking for repair on the vvti cam shaft replacement.this was meant to correct the rattling or knocking sound from the engine v6. Firstly the mechanic condemned the vvti that turns on the hand check that it's the bad one and when we finally fixed the bought part, the engine is not doing slow or running smoothly it goes off when changing the gear to reverse or drive with surging /jacking of the vehicles. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any check engine lights on with the vehicle now? If so, what are they?

Comment: Sadly, not enough information here. In addition to what @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 has asked, please describe what you mean by "slow"